# How to change colour of the Material Design md-input-focused css tag

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have implemented Angular Material Design (0.10) for a older Angular project, it all works however I need to change the default colours with form inputs.

When I focus on an input, there is a dark blue line that appears for that individual input (which is the correct default ng-Material behaviour).

I want to change this to red (to match our existing colours) how can I achieve that?

in the CSS I can see references to md-input-focused but nothing obvious as to change the colours for this? Any suggestions?

```
md-input-container.md-input-focused .md-input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the blue line under an Angular Material Input, try something like this :

```
md-input-container:not(.md-input-invalid).md-input-focused .md-input {
    border-color: red; // Or the color you want
}
```